# convert nginx to apache

Tags: php, apache, nginx, apache2

I am moving a php app from a server that runs ngnix to apache2. I need to convert the nginx configuration to a apache virtual host file.  I have found a lot resources on converting from apache to nginx but not a lot on going from nginx to apache.

Here are the parts I need to convert:

```
rewrite ^.*/files/(.*) /wp-content/blogs.php?file=$1;

# this allows people to use images and css in their maintenance.html file
  if ($request_filename ~* \.(css|jpg|gif|png)$) {
break;
  }

  # this rewrites all the requests to the maintenance.html
  # page if it exists in the doc root. 
  if (-f $document_root/maintenance.html) {
rewrite  ^(.*)$  /maintenance.html last;
break;
  }

  location ~ .php$ {
fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:1026;
fastcgi_index  index.php;
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /data/static/domain$fastcgi_script_name;
include        fastcgi_params;
  }

  location ~ .js$ {
fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:1026;
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /data/static/domain$fastcgi_script_name;
include        fastcgi_params;
  }

}
```

I have already enable the fcgid mod on apache, but if there are any others I also need to enable, please let me know. The area that really confuses me is the last two parts where it has location.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you been running php-fpm on port 1026 before?

Comment: The location stuff is telling nginx what to do with particular paths. So in the case of a .php file, it hands off (passes) to a php-fpm process (running on port 1026). I don't think there is an equivalent in Apache since php runs as a module (and not a separate process as with nginx).

The rewrite directive I would say is the equivalent of Apache's .htaccess files.